# How to combine object array values into 1 array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data object with each object containing a `tags` array, I would like to loop through the object and grab each of the object tags and combine eventually combine the values into 1 array called `selections` on completion of the loop. At the moment however I'm unable to solve this, I have tried pushing the tags into an array then use the underscore _.union method and also tries concatenating each looped array into 1 but with no success. Can anyone recommend a solution?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24qh7zfv/3/

**JS**

```
var selection = [];

var data = ([
    {
        role: "Developer",
        tag: "developer",
        tags: ["Javascript", "CSS", "HTML"] 
    }, {
        role: "Producer",
        tag: "producer",
        tags: ["Project Management", "Pitching", "Billing"] 
    }
]);


for( var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    selection.concat(data[i].tags);
}

console.log(selection);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reassign `selection`, and concat to tho that. so use:

```
for( var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    selection = selection.concat(data[i].tags);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
var selection = [];

var data = [
    {
        role: "Developer",
        tag: "developer",
        tags: ["Javascript", "CSS", "HTML"] 
    }, {
        role: "Producer",
        tag: "producer",
        tags: ["Project Management", "Pitching", "Billing"] 
    }
];


for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    for(var j = 0; j < data[i].tags.length; j++){
      selection.push(data[i].tags[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this.

```
var selection = data.map(function(x){
   return x.tags;
}).join().split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

i think better use concat array function . see concat function in http://skillgun.com/javascript/arrays/tutorial