# Getting nested object array values into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301961/how-to-combine-object-array-values-into-1-array), but with a slight twist in that there other object values beside the arrays and I can't quite seem to figure out the precise syntax to get what I need.

I have something like this:

```
const metadata = [
  {
    stepName: 'Step one',
    controls: [
      {fieldName: 'one', label: 'Field One', type: 'input'},
      {fieldName: 'two', label: 'Field Two', type: 'multiline'}
    ]
  },
  {
    stepName: 'Step two',
    controls: [
      {fieldName: 'three', label: 'Field Three', type: 'input'},
      {fieldName: 'four', label: 'Field Four', type: 'multiline'}
    ]
  }
]
```

...and I want to get all the values for fieldName into there own array so that I end up with something like:

```
someFieldArray = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Just about every attempt I have made chokes somewhere. I know I am close using a combination of iteration and destructuring, but can't quite seem to get the precise syntax and combination correct. I am using ES2015 (6) transpiled using Babel. Any help on how to get this done is appreciated! I can destructure metadata into an object first if that will make things easier ({...metadata}).

Comment: Do you want only unique *fieldName* values, or all values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking for an ES6 approach, this solution might be what you're looking for.

```
[].concat(...metadata.map(item => item.controls.map(obj => obj.fieldName)));
```

Comment: Changed this to the accepted answer since I did mention I am using ES6

Answer (score 3):

In ES5, you could write this.

```js
var metadata = [{ stepName: 'Step one', controls: [{ fieldName: 'one', label: 'Field One', type: 'input' }, { fieldName: 'two', label: 'Field Two', type: 'multiline' }] }, { stepName: 'Step two', controls: [{ fieldName: 'three', label: 'Field Three', type: 'input' }, { fieldName: 'four', label: 'Field Four', type: 'multiline' }] }],
    result = metadata.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.controls.map(function (b) { return b.fieldName; }));
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Perfect, fast, and much less complicated then what I was trying. Thanks!